# Orbits, linear orbits, and invariant subspaces

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-subspace

Dear mathematical hivemind,

I'd be grateful for any leads on the following questions:

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a completely reducible (projective) representation of a connected Lie group $G$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose that  $\mathcal{H}$ has the direct sum decomposition into invariant subspaces $\mathcal{H}= \mathcal{H}_1 \oplus \mathcal{H}_2 \oplus...$ where the restrictions of $\mathcal{D}$ to the $\mathcal{H}_i$ are irreducible. The *$G$-orbit* of a vector $\phi$ in $\mathcal{H}$ is defined as the set $$ \mathscr{O}_G(\phi) = \{\mathcal{D}(g)\phi \; |\; g \in G\}, $$
and the *linear $G$-orbit* of $\phi$ is the linear closure of $\mathscr{O}_G(\phi)$ with respect to the complex numbers. [Note that, for any $\phi \in \mathcal{H}$, the linear $G$-orbit of $\phi$ is equal to one of the $G$-invariant subspaces of $\mathcal{H}$.]

If $G=SU(2)$, then the following holds: the two-dimensional invariant subspace $\mathcal{H}_{1/2}$ (sometimes called the "spin-1/2 representation") is equal to the $SU(2)$-orbit of any vector in $\mathcal{H}_{1/2}$; i.e. $\mathcal{H}_{1/2} = \mathscr{O}_{SU(2)}(\phi)$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal{H}_{1/2}$. In other words: for any $\phi \in  \mathcal{H}_{1/2}$, the $SU(2)$-orbit of $\phi$ is equal to the linear $SU(2)$-orbit of $\phi$.

More generally, consider the following claim: for all $\mathcal{H}_i$, $\mathcal{H}_i = \mathscr{O}_G(\phi)$ for all $\phi \in \mathcal{H}_i$.

**Question 1:** Does this claim hold in general, i.e. for all connected Lie groups? If so, what's the proof? If not, what's a counterexample?

**Question 2:** Does this claim hold for the Poincaré group? If so, what's the proof? If not, what's a counterexample?

**Question 3:** Does this claim hold for $SU(2)$-invariant subspaces of higher dimensions, i.e. dimensions $\geq3$?

Looking forward to your responses!

Comment: Do you require that $G$ be connected? Otherwise, if I understand you correctly, an irreducible 2 dimensional representation of a finite group should provide a counter example. Everything is projective for you, correct? So you are asking if the linear combination two elements of an orbit is on the same line as a third element of the orbit?

Comment: Hi AreaMan, yes, I was thinking of connected Lie groups, thanks for making me clarify. And yes, the thought is that, for any two elements in an orbit, the linear combination of these elements is also in the orbit. [The fact that the representations are projective shouldn't be important in cases such as SU(2), where all projective representations are given by the unitary (linear) ones.] Does that answer your second question adequately?

Comment: Being a projective representation definitely matters, since for SU2 the orbit is compact but the linear orbit is not.

Comment: I see. But surely, this difference between orbits and linear orbits for SU(2) can't be something that applies only to projective representations but not to unitary ones, since (for SU2) the former are just the same as the latter. Right?